# checking if ace exists and if points >21

Tags: java

In my blackjack program i have:

```
Card c = dealCard(deck); //deals the card
updatePoints(players[i], c); // calls updatePoints below.
```

The updatePoints function looks like this:

```
public static void updatePoints(Player player,  Card c){

        int point = c.getValue();
        if(player.getPoints() + point >21 && (player.ace1 == 11 || player.ace2 == 11 || player.ace3 == 11 || player.ace4 == 11)){
            player.points -= 10;
            player.setPoints(point);
            if (player.ace1 == 11){
                player.ace1 = 1;
            }else if(player.ace2 == 11){
                player.ace2 = 1;
            }else if(player.ace3 == 11){
                player.ace3 = 1;
            }else if (player.ace4 == 11){
                player.ace4 = 1;
            }
        }
        if (point == 1){
            //default value for player.ace1 .. player.ace4 is 0


            if(player.ace1 == 0){
                player.ace1 = 11;
                player.setPoints(11);
            }else if (player.ace2 == 0){
                player.ace2 = 11;
                player.setPoints(11);
            }else if (player.ace3 == 0){
                player.ace3 = 11;
                player.setPoints(11);
            }else if(player.ace4 == 0){
                player.ace4 = 11;
                player.setPoints(11);
            }

        }else{
            player.setPoints(point);
        }
        return;
    }
```

for some reason when the points go over 21 this doesnt change the ace value and doesnt adjust the ace.
any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: print the value of `player.getPoints()`  before if statement and check

Comment: Do you get this problem when you already have an ace or when you are just dealt an ace? Or both?

Comment: looks like it doesnt go inside the if?

Comment: Could you provide your getPoints() method?

Comment: ok it looks like it goes inside the first loop and then something goes wrong

Comment: errm, I meant the setPoints(). Is it just points=arg?

Comment: public void setPoints(int points){
  this.points += points;
 }

Comment: If that's your set method then

player.points -= 10;

should be player.setPoints(-10)

Comment: it goes inside : if(player.getPoints() + point >21 && (player.ace1 == 11 || player.ace2 == 11 || player.ace3 == 11 || player.ace4 == 11)){ and after that messes up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20035/discussion-between-user1796681-and-cruncher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems too complicated. Rather than having a variable for each ace, simply keep a *count* of the number of aces you have not reduced to a `1`:

```
private int fullAceCount;
```

update assuming `11` for an ace, but also update the ace count:

```
if (points == 11) { // if it's an ace
    fullAceCount++; // save it for later deduction
}
```

then after updating for any card, check if you you need to deduct `10`

```
if (total > 21 && fullAceCount > 0) {
    total =- 10;
    fullAceCount--; // record that you've used up one of your aces
}
```

and you're done.

Comment: but what if i had ace only one time. This would do it every time even if i have one ace and still go over 21